# Add executable parameter in start menu shortcut

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I've a executable compiled with gcc-g++, say `launcher.exe`. And I want to run it as `launcher.exe --param`. So I make a UWP folder with all assets, binary etc. I can successfully pack the folders in a APPX package with `makeappx.exe` and sing it with `signtool.exe`. It installs and launches successfully. But I can't add the `--param` in that appxmanifest.xml file. The manifest file is as below:

```
 <Applications>
    <Application Executable="launcher.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" Id="test">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="launcher" Square44x44Logo="Assets\test44x44.png" Description="" BackgroundColor="transparent" Square150x150Logo="Assets\test150x150.png">
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait"/>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape"/>
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <rescap3:Extension Category="windows.desktopAppMigration">
          <rescap3:DesktopAppMigration>
            <rescap3:DesktopApp ShortcutPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\test\launcher.lnk"/>
          </rescap3:DesktopAppMigration>
        </rescap3:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
```

So, How can I add that command parameter in shortcut in start menu or in desktop shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the parameter would be hardcoded in the manifest, you might was well change the code of launcher.exe to assume the "--param" whenever it's launched as a packaged app.

If you can't change the code for that binary, you could just add a second EXE, say helper.exe, in your package, make that the entry point and then launch launcher.exe with the desired parameters from there.

Here is a code snippet for helper.exe:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string result = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    int index = result.LastIndexOf("\\");
    string processPath = $"{result.Substring(0, index)}\\..\\Launcher\\Launcher.exe";
    Process.Start(processPath, "--param");
}
```

Full sample project uploaded here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnY4ofULXFV778Dtdxw

You might also find this somewhat related blogpost helpful:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/06/23/accessing-to-the-files-in-the-installation-folder-in-a-desktop-bridge-application/

Comment: I'll share a snippet/sample later today when I find a moment.

Comment: Added a snippet and uploaded a sample now.

Comment: BTW, `Process.Start` opens a console window. Is there any way not to open that window?

Comment: What type of app are you trying to start? If you set the OutputType to "Windows Application" then it won't create a console window.

Answer (score 0):

The [desktop bridge support from Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/uwp-app-package.html), professional edition, can manage the shortcut parameters automatically for your AppX packages. (*the application automatically includes a stub EXE that takes your parameters and passes them to your main app EXE*).

It can also import your AppX package, so you don't have to create the project from scratch. Once the import is done you end up with a project in Advanced Installer from which can create both an AppX and an MSI (*for serving Win7 users for example*).

It also has a VS extension to make build and debugging much easier, you can see it in action in the video from the page linked above.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: I've not  the pro version. Advance installer injects a executable in appx which says to buy it.

Comment: Indeed, that is for trial users. I did mentioned this is a feature supported in the Professional edition. Once you have a license that message is gone.

Comment: With some readings, now I can pack and sign appx package with Windows kits. No need to use that trialware (or may be adware).